# From VMs to Docker - Understanding which containers go on what hosts

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I currently have an Application running on AWS using VMs (EC2) inside a VPC as follows.

- Main LB

  - 2 to 4 EC2 Instances running **LEMP stack** for main API
- EC2 instance running **ReactJS App** for Admin panel
- EC2 instance running **Jenkins**
- 2 EC2 Instances running **LogStash**
- 1 EC2 Instance running **Kibana** and **ElasticSearch**

I'm working on converting all of this to Docker for Production-use (Docker Swarm).  I understand that I can make containers and Dockerfiles for each of these components, but when it comes to deployment, my questions are as follows.

1. All of these components, up until now, could network locally with one another because they all existed in the same VPC.  So they will continue to, I suppose.  But should they all exist in the same Docker Swarm?
2. I'm very accustomed to each component being on its own small server, but now, each will be in it's own container.  So is the idea to have a few larger server, and several containers (as needed) running across the instances?  In other words, some of these components might live on the same servers in the end, but this is the expected behavior when working with containers?

   Or should I still breakup certain    components (ie. ElasticSearch) to be on their own servers?
3. In what cases would you want to have multiple Docker Swarms?  Is it best to assume that anything that is related to this application in any way, should exist within this one swarm?

Comment: These are all good things to think about, but really most of them are matters of opinion and thus aren't really on topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions in order

1. It is not necessary to keep all the containers in the same swarm cluster and you can have similar networking capabilities if you run multiple clusters inside the same VPC. However I would recommend to run them in same cluster(Unless there are strict regulatory requirements or any other strong need is there) so that you can utilize internal networking in docker and linking capabilities to further secure your containers.
2. When you dockerize the current services to multiple containers, based on the granularity, you can independently scale, handle fault tolerance and maintain container life cycle for individual deployments. Since ElasticSearch generally gets lots of requests, it would be logical to seperate it to its own container. Also running the containers in the same host or not is not much of a concern. Infact the Swarm will handle the container placement to different hosts so that if there is a failure in a host, Swarm will provision another container instance in a different host, based on the configurations, which is important for fault tolerance.
3. You can use a single swarm for your usecase for production. One common usecase where you can use multiple Swarm clusters is to seperate different stages of deployment(testing, staging & etc.) to multiple clusters.

Also look at [AWS EC2 container service](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) which is the fully managed docker container service available in AWS. It would be easier to manage containers in AWS, compared to Swarm since its tightly integrated with other AWS services such as IAM, Autoscaling, Load Balancing & etc.